# How to make a HTML5 function to close a script after a certain period of time?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a banner with HTML5 and I need it to close after 20 seconds.

It should be something with dhtml.external.close(); and settimeout after 20s. Can anyone help me with this?

---

Maybe it is possible to do something in such way?

```
 var close = document.createElement('a');
                close.style.display = 'block';
                close.href = "#";
                close.innerHTML = 'CLOSE';
                close.onclick = function() {
                    dhtml.external.close();
                }
                document.body.appendChild(close);

            });
```

but just set the time out somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your banner element has an id `"banner"`, can do this :

```
<div id=banner>BANNER !</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

<script>
document.onload=function(){
  ​setTimeout(function(){
     var banner = document.getElementById('banner');
     banner.parentNode.removeChild(banner);    
  }, 20000);​
};
</script>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/5bDUT/)

Note that many libraries help you making prettiest animation at removal. For example jQuery allows you to fade it out slowly :

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#banner').fadeOut(2000);
}, 20000);​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/VQxzt/)

---

**EDIT :**

Starting from your comment, I can propose you this :

```
var close = document.createElement('a');
close.style.display = 'block';
close.href = "#";
close.innerHTML = 'CLOSE';
close.onclick = function() {
     dhtml.external.close(); // is that a call to a library ? Is that IE specific ?
}
document.body.appendChild(close);
setTimeout(function(){
    document.body.removeChild(close);
}, 20000);
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/EsxKQ/)

Comment: var close = document.createElement('a');
57             close.style.display = 'block';
58             close.href = "#";
59             close.innerHTML = 'CLOSE';
60             close.onclick = function() {
61                 dhtml.external.close();
62             }
63             document.body.appendChild(close);
64  
65         });